# Javascript - array undefined in a prototype?

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototype, push

Here's my code, I'm experimenting stuff with canvas:

```
function Map(){

    this.personnages = new Array();

}

Map.prototype.addPersonnage = function(perso) {

    this.personnages.push(perso);
    console.log(this.personnages);

}

Map.prototype.drawMap = function(){

    console.log(this.personnages);

    for(var i = 0; i < this.personnages.length; i++) {
        this.personnages[i].dessinerPersonnage(context);
    }

}
```

The thing is : the first console.log prints the array just fine, but the second one (in Map.prototype.drawMap) returns "undefined" (therefore the loop can't be executed)...
I guess that functions are called in a correct order :

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('main');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');    
var tilesetImage = new Image();
tilesetImage.src = 'img/tileset.png';

var map1 = new Map();
var player = new Personnage("img/player.png", 7, 14, DIRECTION.BAS);
map1.addPersonnage(player);
tilesetImage.onload = map1.drawMap;
```

I'm kinda new here, please tell me if I gave enough elements.
Thanks in advance, any little help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tilesetImage.onload = map1.drawMap;
```

When `map1.drawMap` is executed, [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) refers to `tilesetImage`, the target of the `load` event. If you want to keep `this` referring to `map1`, you can use [`Function.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
tilesetImage.onload = map1.drawMap.bind(map1);
```

Or you can use a function that calls `drawMap` on `map1` directly.

```
tilesetImage.onload = function () { map1.drawMap() };
```

For more information on `this`, please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword).

Comment: Thanks, so I guess I understood `this` wrong ;) This works now!

Answer (score 1):

When you do

```
map1.drawMap();
```

inside the `drawMap` function, `this` will refer to `map1` object, which has `personnages` variable. That is why `map1.addPersonnage(player);` works properly.

Now, you are simply assigning `drawMap` function to `tilesetImage.onload`. So, when `tilesetImage.onload` is invoked, `this` will refer to `tilesetImage` which will not have `personnages` variable.

That is why the second `console.log` prints `undefined`.

To fix this problem, you should bind the `map1` object to `this` object like this

```
tilesetImage.onload = map1.drawMap.bind(map1);
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of this is not the instance when passing instance function as event handler

Pass a closure or use bind

Its all explained in the following answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941  under the this variable

Answer (score 0):

You call the methode drawMap with help of tilesetImage which is an Image-Object that does not have got the attribute personnages, unless you define it.

This code might help you:

```
tilesetImage.onload = map1.drawMap.bind(map1);
```

Hope this helps a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

here, take the bush function i wrote. it works for standard arrays and associative arrays and jep it also works for Objects to add key/value pairs. also added instanceof defineproperty that checks if we have a fresh browser or an old explorer, if so it wont make every array or object you create a child.

```
    // DIE BUSCHFUNKTION: OBJEKT.BUSCH FUNKTION
// Object/Array.bush() native function that adds a new
// arrayelement to the beginning of the specified.
// Included it also to work for Object Stacks key/value
// pairs and is 2x to 10x times better then default push
if(!('bush' in Object.prototype)){/****/
if((Object.defineProperty instanceof Function))
{(Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype,'bush',{ //modern
  enumerable:false,configurable:true,value:function(key,value)
  {if(key&&value){return this[key]=value;}
     return this[this.length]=key;}}))}
   else{Object.prototype.bush=function(key,value) // compatible
    {if(key&&value){return this[key]=value;}
     return this[this.length]=key;}}};
```